# Wrap git's shell script to add bashrc or equivalent start-up commands

Tags: shell, git, bashrc

My server has a `git` user that handles all git access. You can't log in with it. It's only for git access. That works because GIT comes with a handly shell `/usr/bin/git-shell`.

Login feedback:

```
fatal: What do you think I am? A shell?
Connection to example.com closed.
```

That works beautifully. But the shell doesn't have a `.bashrc` or `.profile` etc. I want to add

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64
```

so my git stops complaining about some custom build stuff. (Everything works, but it keeps warning about a missing version.)

I've added that to `/etc/bashrc`, so all 'normal' users don't have it, but `git` is special. Is there a way to add that export to my git shell? Can I wrap it or something? (I've no idea how passwd works.)